# What is the use of discrete maths and assembly language?

Tags: assembly, discrete-mathematics

I am a student and I came across these two subjects Discrete Maths and Assembly language.
Can any one tell what is the main application and scope of these two subjects in the field of IT.

I would be really thankful if someone could help?

Comment: Assembly is IMO mainly useful these days for understanding how computers compute. That knowledge is important to effectively use higher level languages that aren't too high (it doesn't help you understand Haskell (does anything?) but it helps for C and cousins). It takes away the feeling that "magic is happening".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assembly language is used for processor programming at hardware level. when languages like c were not available. You have to know the register address and write code manually to program the core processor to do whatever you want . Like in robotics etc.
Discrete maths is also related with register programming while designing an microprocessor or circuit for the logic part which gets converted to lower level abstraction in the form of actual capacitors and resistors

Answer (score 2):

Wikipedia says:

> Discrete mathematics is the study of mathematical structures that are fundamentally discrete rather than continuous.

and

> An assembly language is a low-level programming language for computers, microprocessors, microcontrollers, and other programmable devices in which each statement corresponds to a single machine language instruction.

Interestingly, these two subjects are closely related because the data structures a CPU is operating on are all fundamentally discrete. As a mathematician friend of mine  said:

> Computers are just as uninteresting as discrete mathematics: All programs and data are discrete and the number of possible combinations is finite.

Answer (score 0):

Assembly language is a great tool for beginners to understand the basic principles of computer architecture. In addition, it can be used in order to demonstrate the actual difference between low and high-level programming languages.
Changing topic to discrete maths it is necessary to say that its applications arise in a significant number of problems and acquired knowledge of this subject helps a person to study and to deal with other much more difficult and specialised disciplines. That is why some IT-companies pay attention to it while choosing the best candidate for them. The most important chapters in discrete maths are set theory, binary relations, boolean algebra, combinatorics, probability theory and graph theory.